# Guardar datos de un formulario en un XML con php

Tags: php, html5, xml

Como podria hacer para guardar datos de un formulario a un XML ?
La estructura de mi XML es la siguiente:

```
<assessmentItems>

    <assessmentItem complejidad="3" tema="micologia">

        <itemBody> 

            <p>Que Amanita es comestible?</p>

        </itemBody>

        <correctResponse>

            <value>Caesarea</value>

        </correctResponse>

        <incorrectResponses>

            <value>Phalloides</value>

            <value>Muscaria</value>

            <value>Virosa</value>

        </incorrectResponses>

    </assessmentItem>
    </assessmentItems>
```

Mi formulario es el siguiente :

```
            <label for="pregunta"><strong>Pregunta(*):</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="pregunta" minlength="10" id="galdera" required/><br>

            <label for="correcta"><strong>Respuesta correta (*):</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="correcta" id="respuestaCorrecta" required/><br>

            <label for="errada1"><strong>Respuesta errada 1 (*):</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="errada1" id="respuestaErrada1" required/><br>
            <label for="errada2"><strong>Respuesta errada 2 (*):</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="errada2" id="respuestaErrada2" required/><br>
```

......................................... y por aqui seguiria mas formulario....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la versión >5.1.3 de PHP se introdujeron nuevos métodos que nos dan la capacidad de modificar el documento XML.

Estos métodos son:

`SimpleXMLElement::addChild();`
`SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute();`

Recomiendo leer mas al respecto en la doc oficial de PHP:
http://php.net/manual/es/

Con el primer método nos permite añadir un nuevo elemento hijo.
Este acepta dos parámetros:
1-Nombre del atributo
2-Valor del atributo

Con el segundo método agregamos un atributo.
Esta acepta 3 parámetros.
1-Indica el nombre del nuevo elemento
2(opcional)- indica el valor del elemento
3(opcional)- indica el namespace al cual pertenece el elemento

EJEMPLO: 
`

```
<assessmentItem complejidad="3" tema="micologia">

    <itemBody> 

        <p>Que Amanita es comestible?</p>

    </itemBody>

    <correctResponse>

        <value>Caesarea</value>

    </correctResponse>

    <incorrectResponses>

        <value>Phalloides</value>

        <value>Muscaria</value>

        <value>Virosa</value>

    </incorrectResponses>

</assessmentItem>
```

`Primero cargamos el XML y lo transformamos en objeto <br>`
$asmentitems = new SimpleXMLElement('asessmentitem.xml',null,true);`

****Ahora vamos agregar un item 
*Creamos item y lo añadimos al elemento raiz de assmentitems

`$item = $asmentitems->addChild('assessmentItem');`

*Aquí le asignamos el atributo del nuevo item creado;

`$item->addAttribute('complejidad','4');`

*Creamos la estructra dentro del nuevo item

`$item->addChild('itemBody', 'Que Amanita NO es comestible?');
$item->addChild('correctResponse','Pierita');
$item->addChild('incorrectResponses','Aluminio');
$item...`

Para visualizar como queda el XML, podemos mostrarlos en el navegador enviando una cabecera que indique al navegador que el contenido a mostrar no es texto simple n HTML sino XML.

Esto se realiza con:

`header('content-type:text/xml');
echo $asmentitems->asXML();`

Para guardar los cambios del archivo XML es: 

`$asmentitems->asXML('nuevos-asmentitems.xml');`

Espero que le ayude. Saludos!

PD: He de añadir que el código lo he realizado directamente aquí, por lo que es "pseudocodigo", es posible que necesites adaptar algún parámetro. 
Como consejo añadido, si tienes la posibilidad, te diría que modifiques el nombre de cada elemento por algo similar a"amItem" o algo visualmente más cómodo a la hora de realizar tu lógica de modificación, ya que la diferencia entre el conjunto (assessmentItems) y cada item (assessmentItem) es muy similar y puede confundir en si estás tocando un grupo o un elemento, se te va una letra :P


Recuerda valorar positivamente en caso de ser correcta una respuesta, ayudando a otros usuarios a encontrar esta solución.